# Passing method results / overloaded methods - why did this work?

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Let me start by saying that I got this program working, so all I'm looking for is an explanation of why it works.  It was one of those, "Well, maybe this will do it..." moments.

This was a homework assignment, to show method overriding.  The three files are at [Pastebin]
(http://pastebin.com/u/Stephonovich).  UseCarRental is the main class, LuxuryCarRental is the one overriding CarRental.

Currently, in main(), I have this block:

```
rentalCar.setName(name);
rentalCar.setZip(zip);
rentalCar.setCarSize(carSize);
rentalCar.setRentalLength(rentalLength);

    if (carSize.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'L') // Send the below to LuxuryCarRental 
    {
        luxuryRentalCar.setName(name);
        luxuryRentalCar.setCarSize(carSize);
        luxuryRentalCar.setRentalLength(rentalLength);
        luxuryRentalCar.setZip(zip);
        luxuryRentalCar.display();
    }
else rentalCar.display();
```

Previously, I only had this:

```
rentalCar.setName(name);
rentalCar.setZip(zip);
rentalCar.setCarSize(carSize);
rentalCar.setRentalLength(rentalLength);

    if (carSize.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'L')
    {
        luxuryRentalCar.display();
    }

else rentalCar.display();
```

My thought was that since LuxuryCarRental was just using the same gets as UseCarRental, the same values should be there.  The display() portion of LuxuryCarRental is shown here:

```
void display()
{
    chauffeurSelect(); 
    setCarSize("Luxury"); // Seems easier to do it directly here

    totalFee = dailyFee * getRentalLength();
    System.out.println("\nRental summary");
    System.out.println("\n" + getName());
    System.out.println("ZIP code " + getZip());
    System.out.println(getCarSize() + 
            " at $" + getDailyFee() + 
            " for " + getRentalLength() + " days" + 
            " for a total of $" + getTotalFee()); 
}
```

When I ran this with the older portion of main() as shown above, I would get null name, 0 ZIP, Luxury car size, $79.99 daily fee, 0 rental length, 0 total fee.  I understand why I was getting those values; the only thing that was being locally declared was the daily fee, and the car size.  I don't understand why LuxuryCarRental couldn't pull in the name and other values without the dedicated set.  Unless I'm horribly off (very possible), the second block will go through line by line, sending the values to the respective variables, and then as it gets to the if block, it would be true if Luxury was selected, and therefore go to the display() block of that file.  That block, listed above, references the same gets that CarRentalUse does.

Any help in understanding / other critiques is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given us all the code but I expect luxuryRentalCar is a different object to rentalCar. Setting values on one object will usually not affect another object.

Comment: The variables being get/set are in CarRental, and are protected.  LuxuryCarRental and UseCarRental classes extend CarRental.  I thought this meant they would directly have access to that.

You're saying it's because the new object only has a reference to the variable?

Comment: A class defines what value containers an object instance will have. The object instance defines what will be in those value containers will be. Class A extending Class B just means Class A will have all the value containers Class B has with some more.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  So, is there a more elegant way of doing this in the future, or do you have to get/set each one independently?

Comment: Create a constructor that takes all the properties you want to set and call that constructor when you want to create the object. Try and make method generic, like `processExtras()` would do nothing for some cars but lots of things for others.

Answer (score 0):

As @bennyvnq stated, there are two different references to two different objects declared in your main method (i.e. rentalCar and luxuryRentalCar). Classes are different to objects and you can declare as many objects as you want from a class and they will be completely separate from each other except for any static members which will be shared between all the objects of the class (including derived classes).

Read up on polymorphism and design patterns ([http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)) and see if you can change the design of your program. A hint would be to have a RentalCar class that instead of having other classes derive from it, it has fields that are using inheritance and polymorphism to differ behaviour. For example, the RentalCar class might have a DriverType field with DriverType being an interface. You would then have other classes which implement this interface like ChauffeurDriven and SelfDriven that define the differences between the different types of cars. This way, you only have one RentalCar class, and many derived DriverType classes and the design becomes much more robust. In your program you would then have only one RentalCar object which is declared at the beginning of the program and instantiated along with the correct DriverType after user input.

I hope this isn't too confusing but if you can get your head around it and start to use principles like this life becomes much easier!